# How to sum a column value on result return by some search?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

In above link we have a table and show data using a url.
I want to sum `Forks` column on the result return by search something in table.

Eg. if I search `boot` or anything in search box,then it is showing result. I also want to put a footer like this,

```
<tfoot>
    <tr class='info'>
        <td>Sum of Forks</td>
        <td> forks sum of return search result </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

How to do this ?

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/33/)**

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`getData`](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/getData.html) method to achieve what you want.

You can add your own Javascript like so:

```
$('#table').on('search.bs.table', function(param) {
    var data = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData');
  sumForks(data);
})

function sumForks(dataObject) {
  var sum = 0;
    for (var key in dataObject) {
      // skip loop if the property is from prototype
      if (!dataObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

      var obj = dataObject[key];
      for (var prop in obj) {
          // skip loop if the property is from prototype
          if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

          //alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          if(prop === 'forks_count')
            sum += parseInt(obj[prop]);
      }
  }
  $('#table .info .forks_sum').html(sum);
}
```

Updated your fiddle also: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/4005/

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I'm happy to help! If you need further explanation let me know